# MySQL SELECT statement where date equals uk date format

Tags: mysql, date, asp-classic

I'm trying to write an SQL statement to retreive data from any specified date

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(data.DateTimeIn, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM schemaname.data WHERE DATE(data.DateTimeIn) = "anydateinukformat dd/mm/yy"
```

No records are being return when I pass a date e.g. "18/10/2013"

Also, how would I handle dates between for example 1st Sept and 30th Sept

Thanks

John

Answer (score 2):

Use the default `YYYY-MM-DD` format

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(data.DateTimeIn, '%d/%m/%Y') 
FROM schemaname.data 
WHERE DATE(data.DateTimeIn) = '2013-10-18'
```

Comment: ..or else use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: So can I convert my UK date '18/10/2013' in the SQL statement or do I need to convert it before I pass it to the SQL

Comment: @JohnMoore: You can do both. Either convert it before or in the query itself.

Comment: I can easily convert it before, how can i convert it in the query. Thanks